# Using grep -rin with the string value has underscores

Tags: command-line, grep

I am trying to run this command.

```
grep -rin "wp_get_attachment_url" *
```

But the underscores (_) in the string value seems to mess up the grep command.
How do I search the string values that have underscores?

Comment: Can you explain "mess up the grep command"? It works fine here in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `wp_get_attachment_url` is actually an URL that must be interpreted literally, use single quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting characters. Furthermore, use the `-F` option of `grep` to avoid it from interpreting the pattern as a regular expression.

`http://example.com/?id=1` interpreted as a regular expression would match either `http://example.comid=1` or `http://example.com/id=1`, but not `http://example.com/?id=1`.

The command becomes:

```
grep -rinF 'http://example.com/?id=1' *
```

If the pattern contains a `'`, use `'\''` to escape it:

```
grep -rinF 'mornin'\'' all' *
```

A hint: `*` matches all non-hidden files in the current directory. If you want to match dot-files as well, just grep the current directory recursively (`-r`):

```
grep -rinF 'search term' .
```